# How to release a non-null variable for memory leak protection

Tags: kotlin

I don't know how to release a non-null variable of an object in Kotlin. The following code is a TextView list. It is initialized as a non-null object.

```
class aaa{
    var DenomList: MutableList<TextView> = mutableListOf()
    var DenomPCSList: MutableList<TextView> = mutableListOf()
    var DenomAmountList: MutableList<TextView> = mutableListOf()
    var DenomNotationList: MutableList<TextView> = mutableListOf()
    var DenomAmountNotationList: MutableList<TextView> = mutableListOf().
}
```

I want to release the object in the above code for garbage collection in order to protect a memory leak in Kotlin. Please give me some information.

Comment: I assume you can't clear the lists, because you have references to them in other places too?

Comment: @zsmb13 I changed above code. I had aaa object in other place.

Comment: when releasing the instance of `aaa`, if the lists are not referenced somewhere else, they will be garbage collected

Comment: if I use object as follows  : private lateinit var temp:aaa ? . It is impossible garbage collection.

Comment: @김태형 in theory since it's `var temp`, you could do `temp = aaa()`, so that the old object won't be referenced anymore and will be freed (but you will allocate space for the new one)

Comment: one note worth to mention, it's better to name variables with first lower-case letter i.e. `denomList` as it's common code convention

Comment: The code convention is my mind. That is no serious, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reassign them to a different list. If desired to minimize memory use, even cheat a bit:

```
// at top-level, outside any class, or in an object
private val NOT_REALLY_MUTABLE: MutableList<Any> = Arrays.asList<Any>()
fun <T> release() = NOT_REALLY_MUTABLE as MutableList<T>

// in aaa
DenomList = release()
```

This way `release` doesn't allocate anything, just removes a reference to the existing list and possibly allows garbage-collecting it.

But doing things like that to "protect from memory leaks" should only rarely be necessary, and you shouldn't complicate code when it isn't.

Comment: Thank you. It is good example for memory leak protection in Kotlin.

Comment: Your suggested answer addresses the original question but creates an unintended side effect of creating new objects.  Because of this side effect, this is not an optimal solution, ie. any attempt to destroy an instance of class `aaa` with your solution  will still create a memory leak

Comment: The memory used is constant and small, so I don't agree it creates a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

To make the objects eligible for garbage collection there are few options listed below:

1) Remove specific element no longer used. e.g:

```
list.remove
```

2) Clear all the elements in the list

```
list.clear
```

3) Make the whole list assigned to null (after changing to null-able type if applicable)

You need to use to make of the one that is appropriate.

Comment: There's a good alternative to 3) without changing types undesirably.